# Python subprocess module fails when calling awk

Tags: python, bash, awk

Need help in calling the below mentioned awk script using Python subprocess module? .I need to get this working as our monitoring tool requires this. I am a novice in python and I have tried the below and it hasn't helped.

```
>>> print subprocess.check_output(["awk '!/bind|swap|shm/ && $1 !~/#|^$/ {system("if [[ -n $(findmnt -m " $2 ") ]]; then echo Mount " $2 " is mounted.;else echo Mount " $2 " is NOT mounted.;fi")}' /etc/fstab"], shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print subprocess.check_output(["awk '!/bind|swap|shm/ && $1 !~/#|^$/ {system("if [[ -n $(findmnt -m " $2 ") ]]; then echo Mount " $2 " is mounted.;else echo Mount " $2 " is NOT mounted.;fi")}' /etc/fstab"], shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
                                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: Do you have a good reason for using `shell=True`? It makes your job a lot harder here.

Comment: Well, for starters clearly your syntax is invalid. As you can see by the highlighted syntax in your post, you aren't escaping `"` in your command string, so start with fixing that.  `"awk '!/bind|swap|shm/ && $1 !~/#|^$/ {system(\"if [[ -n $(findmnt -m \" $2 \") ]]; then echo Mount \" $2 \" is mounted.;else echo Mount \" $2 \" is NOT mounted.;fi\")}' /etc/fstab"`

Comment: That said, using `system()` inside `awk` is an **extremely** bad idea (as in, parses your data as code, easy route for security vulnerabilites, *really* don't do it bad idea).

Comment: I am a novice. Testing all the options as I would need this working for python 2.7 and 3x

Comment: Note too that it's unreliable to use bashisms like `[[` inside `system()`, which uses `/bin/sh` -- which, on platforms like Debian, will be implemented with dash, which only supports the POSIX-compliant `[` test operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Don't.

The `system()` call in awk is dangerous, and should never be used. For your current use case, it's more appropriate to use native bash instead of awk:

```py
import subprocess
shell_script = '''
set -f # disable globbing
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ $line =~ bind|swap|shm ]] && continue  # skip lines containing "bind", "swap" or "shm"
  [[ $line = "#"* ]] && continue            # skip comments
  [[ $line ]] || continue                   # skip empty lines
  set -- $line                              # word-split line content into $1, $2, etc
  if [[ -n $(findmnt -n "$2") ]]; then
    echo "Mount $2 is mounted"
  else
    echo "Mount $2 is NOT mounted"
  fi
done
'''
print(subprocess.check_output(['bash', '-c', shell_script], stdin=open('/etc/fstab', 'r')))
```

That way you run only *one* shell for the script, instead of having awk use `system()` to invoke a new and distinct shell for every single non-comment line you process.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed Charles, this is really helpful. How can I get python to print only the lines containing the word 'NOT' from the output obtained from running 'print(subprocess.check_output(['bash', '-c', shell_script], stdin=open('/etc/fstab', 'r')))'?

Comment: `[[ $line = *NOT* ]] || continue` would skip any line that doesn't contain `NOT`, inside a `while IFS= read -r line` loop of the type given here. (Or `[[ $line =~ NOT ]] || continue`, which has the same effect).

Comment: Thank you sir, I in fact wanted 'NOT' to be excluded from the final output the while loop produced,so here is how I got the desired output.
I just added a 'done |grep NOT' and that printed just the lines containing NOT.

Comment: Then `[[ $line =~ NOT ]] && continue`, substituting `&&` to `continue` if `NOT` *is* found, instead of it it isn't. Or of course you can use `grep -v NOT` to invert the pattern match.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to escape `"` in your codes, try following once(inside `subprocess.check_output`), fair warning I haven't tested it because of lack of samples. I am simply fixing OP's attempt here, best way to do it within python itself.

```
print subprocess.check_output(["awk '!/bind|swap|shm/ && $1 !~/#|^$/ {system(\"if [[ -z $(findmnt -m \" $2 \") ]]; then echo mount \" $2 \" is NOT mounted.;fi\")}' /etc/fstab"],shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
```